# why wont strcmp() in password work?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

Why does it always show *Invalid Password*? It works in my other program but in this one it doesn't! I literally cant figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAXLTR 15
int login(void);
void welcome(void);
void gotoxy(int x,int y);

int main(void)
{   
    char password[MAXLTR];
    printf("\nEnter password: ");
    //scanf("\n%s",&password);
    ltrcntr = 0;
    while(buffer != 13)
    {
        buffer = getch();
        if(buffer == 13)
                  break;
        printf("\b**");
        password[ltrcntr] = buffer;
        ltrcntr++;
    }
    if(strcmp(password,"dlsu") == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        welcome();
    }
    else
        printf("\nInvalid Password, please rerun the program.\n");


}
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
     HANDLE eric;
     COORD pogi;
     pogi.X = x;
     pogi.Y =y;
     eric = GetStdHandle
     (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
     SetConsoleCursorPosition
     (eric, pogi);
}
int login(void)
{
    char password[MAXLTR],buffer;
    int ltrcntr = 0;
    printf("Enter password: ");
    while(buffer != 13)
    {
        buffer = getch();
        if(buffer == 13)
                  break;
        printf("\b**");
        password[ltrcntr] = buffer;
        ltrcntr++;
    }
    if(strcmp(password,"dlsu")==0)
        return 1;

}

void welcome(void)
{
    system("Color 4F");
    gotoxy(35,56);
    printf("\nWelcome to SPACE INVADERS!");
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look you're nul-terminating `password`.

Comment: Also, maximum 14 letters for a password?

Comment: A debugger makes miracles... :)

Comment: @Mysticial, you just lost 90 reputations!

Comment: @Shahbaz: very true! Everyone knows [you need 25 letters for a good password](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: @Shahbaz No I didn't. I'm just preparing for the hypothetical gold "Pundit" badge... nah... people are more likely to upvote comments since they don't give any rep.

Comment: @Mysticial: Since you answered this in the comments 1 minute before I posted my response I will upvote every comment of yours I see in the future.  You'll get the badge eventually :D

Comment: @EdS. Except that the gold Pundit badge doesn't exist. :)

Comment: @Mysticial: Well ok I don't appreciate being made a fool of, no upvotes for you sir! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C strings are NULL terminated (i.e., the last character is `\0`).  All C functions which operate on strings expect this because it is the only way to know where the string ends.  You array could be filled with anything as it is uninitialized.  Try this:

```
char password[MAXLTR] = {0};
```

`strcmp` expects a NULL terminated string.  Also, if a carriage return is never entered (and I don't even see where `buffer` is declared...) you will overrun your password buffer.

Comment: This won't work if the array has any garbage characters in it.

Comment: @Wug: Not sure what you mean.  The array will be initialized to all `0`'s using the method I suggested.  `0` is a bit special in this case and will initialize every element.  If the value is non-zero then that is not the case.

Comment: Maybe I'm just seeing something I don't recognize.

Comment: @Wug: `char someArray[n] = {0}` will initialize *every* element to `0`.  `char someArray[n] = {1}` would initialize *only the first* element to `1`, and likewise `char someArray[n] = {1, 1}` would initialize the first two, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked it up.  Smells like a language smell to me

Comment: @Wug: "Language smell"?  I don't understand why you would think this a bad thing. I think the term "smell" is bantered about *far* to often...

Comment: By smell I mean something weird that it doesn't look like it would do but does.

Comment: @Wug: Well it assumes that you know the language I suppose.  It is perfectly clear to me and I would imagine anyone else who has a bit of experience in C.  It's very common to initialize arrays to `0`, so the syntax supports it.  You could say the same for many  constructs in other languages which amount to syntactical sugar.

Comment: @Jack: Not sure if you're being sarcastic, but I actually do love the way C works :D

Comment: @EdS.: I'm not. C is my lover language. Actually, I prefer C instead of C++ or C# languages. :)

Comment: @Jack: As do I (though I'll take C# for building a quick UI any day).  And javascript? ...no thanks, I prefer one equality operator thank you very much :D

Comment: @Mysticial: I know about javascript.. xD I used it a lot with the PHP language(some years ago). I created some users-scripts for greasemonkey too. Today I use with ASP.NET when I need to write something for web,but it's rarely.. I really prefer desktop platform.  But a script language very cool that I look at sometimes is the Lua programming language.

Comment: (sorry for my bad english. I'm not a native speaker.)

Comment: @Jack: Glade?  As in, the air freshener?  Your English seems fine to me BTW

Comment: @EdS.: Not as the air freshener or AJAX. xD But like this: http://glade.gnome.org/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not null-terminating the password buffer before using `strcmp`. C string utilities expect strings to be null-terminated.

After you've finished reading in each character of the password, add a null character, '\0' to password:

```
password[ltrcntr] = '\0';
```

Make sure that you've allowed an extra element in the array size for the null character.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your array isn't NULL terminated.  Either zero it out first or change your loop to look like this:

```
while(ltrcntr < MAXLTR - 1) // protect from password that's too long
{
    buffer = getch();
    if(buffer == 13)
              break;
    password[ltrcntr] = buffer;
    ltrcntr++;
    printf("\b**");
}
password[ltrcntr] = 0; // null terminate after last character
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not ensuring that as the password is checked character by character, that a terminating '\0' follows the last character. The password is not zero-terminated. That is pretty much all.

Comment: He's not storing the carriage return, he's checking for it and breaking the loop early.

Comment: Hmmm okay 'while(buffer != 13)' confused me. My bad, i guess it is null terminated string. Edited my post

Comment: Understandable, it's not the most idiomatic way to read a string.

Answer (score 0):

Reading character by character is unnecessary.

```
fgets(password,MAXLTR,stdio);
```

This stops after a newline or EOF, nul-terminates the string, and won't overrun the buffer.